# Amplify Cognito Auth, Can I verify the forgotten password code on its own page?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-amplify

I am using Amplify and creating a forgotten password journey for my app. I am using this function:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

// Send confirmation code to user's email
Auth.forgotPassword(username)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Collect confirmation code and new password, then
Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(username, code, new_password)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

As specified in the docs [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/#change-password)

What I want to achieve is a 3 page journey.

1. enter email address
2. enter code (and have it validated before moving on to the next page)
3. enter new password

The issue that I am having is that the provided forgotPasswordSubmit function takes all 3 args, when at this point, I only want to send 2 (email and code).

My plan was to send the email, and the code, and an empty string for the password, and then check the returned errors to see if there was one relating to the code being incorrect however I only ever get an error for the password being invalid.

Is there a way that I can get amplify to send back all errors at once (in this case the password being invalid but ALSO the code not being correct), or is there a nicer way of doing this?

I have searched for ages for an answer before asking here so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hey, did you found any way to do this?

Comment: I didn't i'm afraid. I'm hoping that more people find this post and a solution is made.

Answer (score 1):

I figured about a way to get around this problem. It's definitely not ideal, but it works!

1. Try forgotPasswordSubmit with a short invalid password.
2. Check if the error message is about invalid code

```js
submitVerificationCode() {
  try {
  
    await Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(
      username,
      confirmationCodes.join(""),
      "1111"
    );
  } catch (error) {
    if (
      error.message ===
      "Invalid verification code provided, please try again."
    ) {
      // Ask valid code again
    } else {
      // If the error message is not Invalid verification code error
      // then move to the next step: get a new password from the user
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this problematic since the user then will need to reset their password again with a different code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only do it as a [two stage process](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/#forgot-password).

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

// Send confirmation code to user's email
Auth.forgotPassword(username)
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

// Collect confirmation code and new password, then
Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(username, code, new_password)
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. In our website, the forgotPassword flow looks like this:

request a verification code -> verify code -> input new password

But with the AWS amplify methods, I can ONLY do the step 2nd and 3rd TOGETHER.

Hope if there is a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Not just me then! It is a tad annoying. I never found a way but hopefully one day someone will see this and let us know.

Comment: @thomasters check my new Answer! I figured out how to get around the problem :)